# Custom module magento 2.1 But 404 not found

Tags: magento-2.1, module

I created a simple custom module for my magento 2.1
I followed this article
http://javascriptsolution.com/create-custom-module-in-magento-2-1/

Then when I run my localhost/myshop/excellence/custom/index I have 404 not found..

Any help please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello welcome to SE. You need to provide more details or place some code so people can help you out.